# verifying stripe payments thought database

Tags: php, pdo

so i have a basic strip checkout page which works great but after payment is taken  the user is sent to a confirm page which gives them the item. The problem im having is if you sub to one user you can save the url of the confirm page then edit the users id at the end and then just keep visiting the confirm page to sub to other users you have no paid for.

checkout.php

```
$stmt2 = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ');
$stmt2->execute( array($user ) ) ;
$row2 = $stmt2->fetch();



$_SESSION['price'] = $row2['price'];


$price = $row2['price'];
$fee = '1.50';

$lineItems = [
    [
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => 'GBP',
            'product_data' => [
                'name' => 'Geatzo Payment',
            ],
            'unit_amount' => $price*100 ,    //  convert to cents
            'tax_behavior' => 'exclusive'
        ],
        'quantity' => 1
       
    ],
    [
        'price_data' => [
            'currency' => 'GBP',
            'product_data' => [
                'name' => 'Tax',
            ],
            'unit_amount' => $fee * 100,   //  convert to cents
            'tax_behavior' => 'exclusive'
        ],
        'quantity' => 1
        
    ]
   
];



// Create Stripe checkout session
$checkoutSession = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
    'line_items' => $lineItems,
    'mode' => 'payment',
    'success_url' => "https://url.com//checkout-success.php?provider_session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}&user={$user}",
    'cancel_url' => "https://url.com/timeline.php?user={$user}"
]);

// Retrieve provider_session_id. Store in database.
//$checkoutSession->id;
```

checkout-success.php

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['provider_session_id'])) {
    die();
}
$user = $_GET['user'] ;
$_SESSION['price'] = '11.01' ;


$datenow = date('d/m/Y ');

$datefurture = date("d/m/Y",strtotime("+1 months"));

echo $datenow ;




$sql = "INSERT INTO subs (to_user, from_user, date,to_date,price) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt= $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$user, $_SESSION['userid'], $datenow,$datefurture,$_SESSION['price']]);




$sql2 = "INSERT INTO admin_pay (to_user, from_user, date,price) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
$stmt2= $db->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->execute([$user, $_SESSION['userid'], $datenow,$_SESSION['price']]);



    $gggggggggggggggg = "UPDATE users SET balance=balance+? WHERE id= ?";
    $dadasdasd = $db->prepare($gggggggggggggggg);
    $dadasdasd->execute(array($_SESSION['price'],$user ));



echo "Payment confirmed you can now view this user's posts. Remember subscriptions are automatically canceled after 30 days.";
```

so i could simply go to [https://url.com//checkout-success.php?provider_session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}&user=1](https://url.com//checkout-success.php?provider_session_id=%7BCHECKOUT_SESSION_ID%7D&user=1)

and id be subbed to user 1  i can then change the 1 to 2 i be subbed to user 2

Is there any better way of doing this ? I was thinking maybe on the checkout page i insert a value into the database then check on the confirm page if the value is there ? And after giving the user the reward remove the value ? But then you could go to check out page  ( not pay ) then vist the url and still get rewarded

thoughts on how to get past this

Comment: For stipe, you should use the payment_intent.succeeded (event type) to update the db table. For details, please see [official documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)